# Asserting in NUnit that a collection is in the same order as an expected collection

Tags: collections, nunit, assertions

I know how to check that a collection is ordered by some property:

```
Assert.That(actual, Is.Ordered.By("Foo"));
```

How can I assert that *actual* contains the elements (1,2,5,3,4) in this specific order (without writing a custom comparer).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedIEnumerable, actualIEnumerable);
```

This checks that the items are equal and are in the same order.

I'm fairly sure that when you use Assert.That on a collection, you get collection assert functionality. So you can say stuff like

```
Assert.That(collection, Is.EqualTo(expectedCollection)); // Same order
```

or

```
Assert.That(collection, Is.EquivalentTo(expectedCollection)); // Same item count
```

as well as stuff like

```
Assert.That(collection, Has.Count.EqualTo(expectedSize));
```

The Has keyword opens you up to the stuff that was specific to collection asserts, and is really useful.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about CollectionAssert

Comment: Having SO around makes me much more lazy regarding googling.